# React - how to stub component methods that use property initializer syntax?

Tags: reactjs, sinon, ecmascript-next

I'm finally updating my components from `React.createClass()` to ES6 classes. The first error I'm seeing in my tests is that some of my `sinon.stub()` calls are failing because `jscodeshift -t react-codemod/transforms/class.js` converted my component methods to use the property initializer proposal, i.e.

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchSomeData(this.props);
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.someProp !== this.props.someProp) {
      this.fetchSomeData(nextProps);
    }
  }
  fetchSomeData = (props) => {
    ...
  };
  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

My question is: how can I stub `fetchSomeData()` using this new syntax? My tests looks like `sinon.stub(Foo.prototype, 'fetchSomeData');` which no longer works, assuming because `fetchSomeData` isn't on the prototype anymore.

Thanks!

Comment: ES7 was released *last year* (2016). Property initializers are a *proposal*.

Comment: Does your test have access to the instance of the component? If so you could do sinon.stub(componentInstance, 'fetchSomeData') and then componentInstance.render();

Comment: @jeznag good point, thanks. Didn't think of that. But I let enzyme handle the render lifecycle, and I don't think intervening with that would be a good solution for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this example, `fetchSomeData()` does in fact get attached to `this` and not to `Foo.prototype`, so there is absolutely no way to stub the method before creating the instance. The workaround is to move the logic in `fetchSomeData()` to a different location that *can* be stubbed. Or use a different syntax to define the method.